# Testing a method that clones a mocked parameter

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, clone, mockery

I have a class, `getPaginatedQuery`, that as its first step immediately clones one of its parameters:

```
public function getPaginatedQuery(Builder $query, $limit = null, $offset = null)
{
    $constrainedQuery = clone $query;
    ...
}
```

Cloning of the `Builder` object is accomplished by its `__clone` magic method.

I am trying to unit test this method by passing it a mocked `Builder` instance for `$query`:

```
$query = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder');
$relation->getPaginatedQuery($query, 2, 1);
```

My test fails with a fatal error: `__clone method called on non-object`.  I've tried defining an expectation for `__clone` on my `$query` object, but I get the same error:

```
$query = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder');        
$clonedQuery = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder');
$query->shouldReceive('__clone')->andReturn($clonedQuery);

$relation->getPaginatedQuery($query, 2, 1);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`Eloquent\Builder` actually contains (as a member) an instance of `Query\Builder`, and its magic `__clone` method calls `clone` on this underlying `Query\Builder` object:

```
/**
 * Force a clone of the underlying query builder when cloning.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __clone()
{
    $this->query = clone $this->query;
}
```

Since you're mocking `Eloquent\Builder`, it doesn't actually have an underlying `$this->query` member because that would be set in `Eloquent\Builder`'s constructor, which never gets called in a fully mocked object.

To get around this, you need to create a partial mock of `Eloquent\Builder`, and tell it to [run its *real* constructor](http://docs.mockery.io/en/stable/reference/startup_methods.html#quick-reference) with a mocked instance of `Query\Builder`:

```
$baseQuery = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder');
$query = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder', [$baseQuery])->makePartial();

$relation->getPaginatedQuery($query, 2, 1);
```

Now when `clone $query` is called in `getPaginatedQuery()`, the mocked `Eloquent\Builder` instance will be able to call `clone` on *its* mocked `Query\Builder` instance.